# getChildFragmentManager for non support fragment as nested fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-nested-fragment

I'm using an nested fragment which is of class Fragment, as opposed to SupportFragment (v4).
I should use getChildSupportManager to handle this properly, but that suspects v4 support fragments, and I have a regular Fragment (which I can't change, it comes from a library).

How would I be able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> I should use getChildSupportManager to handle this properly, but that suspects v4 support fragments

AFAIK, there is no `getChildSupportManager()` method in Android. There is `getChildFragmentManager()`.

If you are using `getChildFragmentManager()` from a `FragmentActivity`, you need to give it a fragment from the Android Support package backport (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`). If you are using `getChildFragmentManager()` from a regular `Activity` on API Level 17+, you need to give it a native fragment (`android.app.Fragment`).

> I have a regular Fragment (which I can't change, it comes from a library).

Then set your `minSdkVersion` to 17 and use `Activity` instead of `FragmentActivity`.